# What is the story of war that started with "if"?

Tags: ancient-history, military, war

I was told about a story, of how one army sent terms to another army threatening 'if' they did not obey them, they would be punished. The receiving army replied to the threat with one word "if". I would really like to know if this story is a real historical event and if so what time period/era.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Recorded in Plutarch's [*De garrulitate*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0288%3Asection%3D17), this is an example of a [Laconic phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laconic_phrase#Examples):

> After invading Greece and receiving the submission of other key
>   city-states, Philip II of Macedon sent a message to Sparta: "If I
>   invade Laconia you will be destroyed, never to rise again." The
>   Spartan ephors replied with a single word: "If" (αἴκα). Subsequently
>   neither Philip II nor his son Alexander the Great attempted to capture
>   the city.

Comment: Great answer! The only problem is that you have clearly quoted a large portion of it from somewhere, without providing a link to that place (or at least a book reference if it was transcribed). Technically, that's against StackExchange policy. Could you possibly add that link?

Comment: The link (from Plutarch) can be found as reference #27 in the Laconic phrase Wikipedia article

Comment: @T.E.D. The quote is taken directly from the provided link, but I've edited to make the source more obvious.